# setarch unrecognized architecture

Tags: linux, process, exec

So I'm trying to use `setarch` to add the `-R` flag on a program, but it seems whenever I do any sort of flag I keep getting unrecognized architecture. I've done arch to figure out what bash is (x86_64) but I'm not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setarch` takes its arguments in a weird order: the architecture name must come first, before any option.

```
setarch x86_64 -R bash
```

Or, to avoid hard-coding the architecture:

```
setarch "$(arch)" -R bash
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Apologies, the man file was not really all too clear. and I was hoping to avoiding the hard coding too thank you! Is it too much to also ask how did you figure the avoidance?